# how to convert string to array in Spark Scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark

I have a json file, after spark.read.json, one of the column (name: js) has the following format:

```
{"pp":1,"its":"[{"def":false, "val":3},{"def":true, "val":2},...]"}
```

I need to explode "its", so I can know each def, and each val inside, and the numbers of defs and vals are not certain.

When I read its, by using

```
val df = tmp.select($"js.its")
```

df is a DataFrame of string. Can I convert it back to Array so that I can use explode, or any other ways to know all the defs values, and all the vals values?

many thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could use collect_list to convert it back to array in this manner (column names are just a suggestion:)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
augmented = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("exploded").as("array"))
```

Comment: It did convert the column to an array, however, when you do show, it shows [[{...}]], and when i do explode, it showed the same results as when i did tmp.select($"js.its").